# How to repeat the same value till last textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I plan to repeat the double clicked textbox value to end of textbox. My form contains ten text box with 10 different values. If I click the third textbox the value of third textbox should repeat till 10th textbox. but 2 and 1st textbox retain same value. I have include code in codepen please find the below link.

http://codepen.io/nachicode/pen/dXKaaA/

Code Snippet:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="3" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="4" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="5" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="6" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="6" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="7" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="7" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="8" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="8" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="9" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="9" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="10" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="10" />
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").dblclick(function() {
    //Code here
  });
});
```

Comment: its unclear what u try to achieve

Comment: Please show code and ask specific questions about the code. As it stands this is a general _show me the codez_ request and will down voted and likely closed.

Comment: And where did you get stuck when you tried to attempt this? What went wrong?

Comment: @george, I given everything in description. If it is unclear to you then I will explain once again. My agenda is to repeat a textbox value till end of the column. If I make a double click on third textbox then the value of third textbox should repeat till 10th textbox.

Comment: @David Thomas, I am stucks at getting the index of current textbox value, then store the value of selected textbox and repeat the value to rest of the textbox.

Comment: If that's where you're stuck that's fine, but show your code. That way you might get some advice to see how you might improve, and learn something useful for the – inevitable – next time.

Comment: @David Thomas, Thanks for your advice, now I segregate the code above. I want to find the textbox index value, then store the value  and repeat the stored value to rest of the checkbox. If I clicked the third textbox, instance third checkbox value is 3 that value repeat from 3rd textbox to 10th textbox. I hope I conveyed my requirement and waiting for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").dblclick(function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('td').index() + 1;
    var rows = $(this).closest('tr').nextAll().addBack();
    rows.find('td:nth-child(' + index + ') input').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="3" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="4" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="5" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="6" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="6" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="7" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="7" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="8" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="8" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="9" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="9" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="10" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="10" />
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where we using t variable? and what is the uses of index and rows variable?

Comment: @NachiappanR - Check the updated answer. Double Click will update the selected column only.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is the following:

```
// select all <input> elements within a <td> element,
// bind the anonymous function of the on() method as
// the 'dblclick' event-handler:
$('td input').on('dblclick', function() {

  // find the ancestor <tr> or the dblclick-ed element:
  var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr'),

    // get all subsequent siblings of the current <tr>,
    // and add the current <tr> back to that selection
    // with addBack():
    laterSiblingRows = currentRow.nextAll().addBack(),

    // find relevant <input> elements within the <tr>
    // elements:
    laterInputs = laterSiblingRows.find('input');

  // update the value of those <input> elements to
  // the value of the dblclick-ed element:
  laterInputs.val(this.value);
})
```

```js
$('td input').on('dblclick', function() {
  var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr'),
    laterSiblingRows = currentRow.nextAll().addBack(),
    laterInputs = laterSiblingRows.find('input');

  laterInputs.val(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="3" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="4" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="5" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="6" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="6" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="7" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="7" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="8" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="8" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="9" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="9" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="10" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input Type="text" Value="10" />
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c22xwe64/).

References:

- [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thanks, its working like a charm But I need to get repeated values within same column not repeat to second column, Is it possible?

Comment: If I clicked the second column & 4th textbox means it should only reflect to second column 4th to 10th textbox instead it should reflect on both the columns. Kindly advice on this.

Comment: That's easy enough to do, but it wasn't mentioned - or specified - in your question. I'm not intending this as a complaint at all, but you need to be very specific and clear in your questions to prevent misunderstandings :)

Comment: :-) Thanks for your advice Man.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input").dblclick(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();

        for(start=id; start<=10; start++)
        {
            $('input[value="'+start+'"]').val('hello');
            //$('input[value="enter highlight"]')
        }
    });
```

Comment: But my form may contain unlimited textbox not only 10 textboxes, How I calculate this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I won't post ready-to-use code here, but you could give your inputs ids like "box1", "box2" etc. When you double click the input, you can get it's id, get the index of it and then increment the index and reference the next inputs by "box" till you either can't find an element with such id or reach a special number, like 10 in your case.

Some pseudo-code:

```
var clickedBoxId = this.ID; // "this" should point to the box clicked
var index = clickedBoxId.Replace('box','');

for( int i = index; i <= 10; i++ )
{
    var anotherBox = document.getElementById('box' + i);
    if( anotherBox !== 'undefined' )
    {
        anotherBox.value = this.value
    }
}
```

Note, that I don't use javascript frequently, so the code should be understood as pseudo-code and won't work when you just copy-paste it.

Comment: But my form may contain unlimited textbox not only 10 textboxes, How I calculate this dynamically?

Comment: Well, it depends on where this textboxes come from. Do you generate them in your backend? Are they generated in the frontend by some js?

Comment: yes its auto generating based on the database count.

Comment: Then you can just store the count somewhere in a hidden-tag or even put it into your js script directly from the backend. Btw: Note, that the marked solution is good enough for now, but when you'll change the structure of the table somehow later, it will break immediately.